# FormControl debounceTime not available in angular 5 (ionic 3)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

I just updated angular in ionic app from version 4 to 5. I have some search FormControl inputs that allow user to search a database via ajax requests.
I used debounceTime() method to delay ajax search request but after angular upgrade this method is no longer available. I removed this method call but now a new request is made on every user key press on android.

Is there any other way to achieve this delay?

```
this.searchControl.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(2000)
        .subscribe(search => this.getCities(search));
```

Comment: you can try to use some thing like 
`this.<form>.get('<controlname>').valueChanges.subscribe`

Comment: I just edited my question... I forgot to set debounce time in seconds... I don't see how you set the delay in your example

Comment: have you added the import for debounce down

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks... I actually forgot to import debounceTime... can you post the answer so I can accept it as correct one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just like you can see in **[Ionic docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#rxjs-552-updates)**:

> RXJS 5.5.2 Updates
>
> The recent update of RXJS includes a change in how operators are
>   applied.
>
> Traditionally, operators were applied like this:
>
> ```
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
>
> export MyClass {
>
>   someMethod(){
>     // Using Reactive Forms
>     this.input.valueChanges
>     .debounceTime(500)
>     .switchMap(inputVal => this.service.get(inputVal))
>     .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **This approach involved modifying the Observable prototype and patching
>   on the methods**.
>
> RXJS 5.5 introduces a different way to do this that can lead to
>   significantly **smaller code bundles**, lettable operators.
>
> To use **lettable operators**, modify the code from above to look like
>   this:
>
> ```
> // Use Deep imports here for smallest bunlde size
> import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';
> import { switch } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap'; // <- Please read the update!
>
> export MyClass {
>
>   someMethod(){
>     // Using Reactive Forms
>     // We use the new `.pipe` method on the observable
>     // too apply operators now
>
>     this.input.valueChanges
>     .pipe(
>       debounceTime(500),
>       switchMap(inputVal => this.service.get(inputVal))
>     )
>     .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **This slight change allows only import the operators we need in our
>   code. This will result in a smaller, faster application. This example
>   uses Deep Imports, which allow the module we want to import to be
>   isolated.**

So basically you'd need to slightly change the import statement to use *deep imports*

`import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';`

And then use the `debounceTime` inside of the `pipe(...)` method:

```
this.input.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      // you can chain more operators if needed ...
      // ...
    )
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

You can still use the old way (since this is not a breaking change yet) but using **lettable operators will result in a smaller, faster application**.

---

**UPDATE**

Just like [@lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586880/lifetimes) mentioned in his comment (and as you can see **[here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts#L84)**), this import

```
import { switch } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
```

should be replaced by

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
```

when using newer versions.

Comment: thanks for the answer... it's clear and it's working now... I'll accept it as the correct answer...

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @SašoKovačič :)

Comment: Ty for this. I know it's a quote so won't edit it but they've renamed `import { switch }` to `import { switchMap }` for anyone using newer versions

Comment: Thanks @lifetimes! I've added that to the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

May be help this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formcontrol-debounce):

```
let debounce = this.name.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000), // delay 1000 msec
  distinctUntilChanged() // only for changed value
);
debounce.subscribe(changes => {
  console.log(changes);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the syntax for using Rxjs operators has changed in the next version of Rxjs (used in angular 5). Try this:

```
this.searchControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(2000))
    .subscribe(search => this.getCities(search));
```

Import `pipe` and `debounceTime` if necessary

Comment: changed in [rxjs 5.5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) to be precise...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's not working... I get "debounceTime is not defined"..

Comment: @SašoKovačič can you show your import statements in the question?

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

Comment: As Rahul Singh suggested I just needed to import debounceTime and it's working now... no need for the pipe part...

Comment: What's your version of Rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

(12th April 2019) There have been changes since these answers were posted.  Now `debounce` takes a `durationSelector: (value T) => SubscribableOrPromse<any>`.  So the solution becomes:

```
this.searchControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(() => interval(2000)))
    .subscribe(search => this.getCities(search));
```