# How do I abort an Ionic promise

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-promise

I'm making a list of items and everytime that the user input some value it calls the `listVendas` function that searches immediately in the API, but this cause a bunch of requests, and some requests can finish before others, so my question is.

How can I abort a Promise so I can create a new one?

```
listVendas(event?: any) {
    let codigovenda;

    if (event) {
        codigovenda = event.value;
    }

    if (typeof this.promise != 'undefined') {
        // HOW DO I ABORT THE PREVIOUS PROMISE
    }

    this.promise = this.vendaProvider.getAll(codigovenda);

    this.promise.then(data => {
        this.vendas = data;
    })
}
```

Comment: look into `debounce`ing your requests. (eg. https://vanillajstoolkit.com/helpers/debounce/)

Comment: ES6 promises do not support cancellation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a lot, and you can't abort a promise, so my solution was to don't make the request everytime the user type something, instead of that I created a button to make the request

```
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="listVendas()">
        <ion-card class="search">
            <ion-icon class="icon-search" name="search"></ion-icon>
            <ion-input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" formControlName="codigovenda"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon class="icon-camera" name="camera" (click)="scanBacode()"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card>
        <ion-row class="row-submit" justify-content-center>
            <button ion-button full icon-start type="submit">
                Buscar
            </button>
        </ion-row>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic you can use the rxjs **[switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)** operator and **[debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html)** operator to do this very easily.

**[example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472887/formcontrol-debouncetime-not-available-in-angular-5-ionic-3)**

Comment: But I call te `listVendas` with a `ionChange` where do I create the debounce?